# Confusion On Certain Comments Against Question Asked

Tags: discussion

This is question Related My Past Question on StackOverflow which is deleted on my request.

The Title is :- [Diference Behaviour of Dispose Method Between Winforms and Textboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645786/diference-behaviour-of-dispose-method-between-winforms-and-textboxes) (10k only - right now)

The above question I asked to expand my knowledge, and no response I have get against it. No problem but there are certain comments on it which I do not understand. I am confused by them. That's why I am  here for your kind help.

The comments i have received from many users indicate that they do not understand my question due to my lack of English knowledge, but they do not forget to mention that my question is reasonable and valid.

My question here is, if they do not understand my question then how can they comment on it like it is valid and reasonable question. If it is valid and reasonable then how can they down voted against it.

If it is valid and reasonable than they should try to edit it, as many my questions are edited.

This kind of certain confusion on my mind makes me hope I can clear by our community.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would love to take a look at your question.

Comment: @jjnguy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645786/diference-behaviour-of-dispose-method-between-winforms-and-textboxes (10k only)

Comment: From what I can tell, that looks like a great question, besides the lack of experience using the english language.  It should be given a second life, but it needs some editing.

Comment: @mahesh I tried to edit it, but it was pretty incomprehensible; read through it and let us know if it sounds like what you meant to say, and then it can be undeleted

Comment: I made lots of changes to your question.  Please change it if my edits destroyed your original meaning.  But, I hope I improved it overall.

Comment: @jjnguy Sir, You have perfectly edited it. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a few comments regarding your post here.

It may just be me, but I feel that using the term 'Sir' to refer to refer to us (meta users) feels like you are mocking the users.

Let me explain why I feel that way.  Usually we have a [cordial](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cordial) relationship on all of the sites here, and using 'Sir' just feels like you are mocking the process.  I know that is not your intent, but I don't feel it is appropriate here.  I appreciate that you want to be formal, and address us (other users) with respect, but it is unnecessary.  Please be less formal, and address us as peers, because that is what we are, friends.

Another thing.  We welcome non-native English speakers because we need all of the participation on Stack Overflow that we can get.  That is what makes the site so successful. (lots of participation)  But, we expect the questions to be clear enough that we can understand the meaning.  English is the 'accepted' language of the sites.

Also, thank you for coming to meta with your concern.  Please don't run away from the site.  Your contributions (questions and answers) are welcome and necessary.

--jjnguy (Justin Nelson)

*I usually don't sign posts, but I feel like since you are trying to be respectful, I should as well.*

Comment: I think you'd find that 'Sir' is used as a term of respect - not mockery - where Mahesh comes from.

Comment: Sir, It's my respect to each and every people. and it's part of my life. i am not underestimate anybody. sir i feel bad to addressing people directly to whom i got knowledge. those person is most respectful for me who provide the knowledge. and for that i am here. but i will obey what u suggest but sir it's too hard for me.

Comment: I had to mark that as a great comment

Comment: @mahesh, I'm glad that you have respect for the people who provide you knowledge.  And, if you feel it necessary to address them as Sir, then you should do it.  Just be careful.

Comment: @mahesh: in many parts of the world, "Sir" is used only when addressing those of higher social status than yourself. To use that term when addressing a peer sounds strange. It could sound as though you are trying to make a peer feel that you are treating them as a superior, perhaps so that they will like you better. At least on SO, I think you would get a better reaction if you treated everyone as equal to yourself (except, maybe, for Jon Skeet).

Answer (score 4):

It is not just language. The post in question is also the third in a series that started with a question about TableLayouPanels and Editboxes and then there were 2 about TextBoxes and Dispose. The LayoutPanel was shown to be innocent.

So apart from the language problems, you should put a little more effort in preparing the question. We don't want to look at a fragment from a large program with the question "how to fix this".  Usually it is the wrong fragment.

In your case you should have created a new, empty project with 1 (maybe 2) Textboxes, a Button and a few lines of code. That takes programming skills, not English.

You would still have to describe the problem in terms of what you wanted and what actually happened but that would have been so much easier.

And keep improving existing question, don't post new ones for the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to comment intelligently without reviewing the post in question. I suggest that the next time this happens to you, that you not delete the question, and leave it available for review.

**EDIT**: I did find the question: [Diference Behaviour of Dispose Method Between Winforms and Textboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645786/diference-behaviour-of-dispose-method-between-winforms-and-textboxes), for 10k users. I wouldn't have downvoted, myself. But, and this may be hard for you to hear, Mahesh: your question is not clear at all, and I fear it's a language barrier. I sense you're asking a valid question, but programming in general demands precise language, and I had to stare at your question for a while before I figured out what was being asked.

I didn't find any of the comments (at least, those still present on your question as of now) disrespectful.

I don't think people should have downvoted you. I wish human languages didn't present the barriers they do. But they do, and you're going to have a difficult time getting good answers until your English improves. Keep asking questions, though.

Comment: Sir thank you very much i will try hard on it.

Comment: note: people didn't downvote *him*, they downvoted the *question*.  That's perfectly acceptable for a poorly worded question, providing guidance to people who find it later.  We need to remember that it's about the question (and answers), not the asker.

Comment: @tvanfosson: point taken. They downvoted the question to -4, though, and I think that was inappropriate. Folks were just piling on.

Answer (score 2):

I mean no disrespect, especially since I would be even worse trying communicate in another language than English, but I've looked at your questions and you really need to work on your English skills if you expect to make good use of this site. I mean, I sort of understand that you think your question was unfairly commented against and downvoted, but I honestly have no idea what you're trying to say by:

> that kind of certain confusion on my mind hope it will clear by our community and I do believe on it.

That's the case with many of your questions.  The language is so poor as to nearly be unintelligible.  We recognize the words but they're often strung together in a way that makes little or no sense.

You might be an excellent programmer, but if you want to make the best use of SO, asking and answering questions, you'll need to work hard on your English communication skills.

Comment: Sir, am well come your answer and try to work hard on it. thank you very much.