# Why was I downvoted?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I am not against downvoting; I know downvoting encourages us to modify ourselves for the better.

However I think that it would be more helpful if it showed us what the mistake is that we made. If we know which points are wrong then we can modify our posts for the better and avoid making those same mistakes in the future. But if I don't know what the mistake is then how can I try to learn from it?

At least a reason should be there to help us improve. Otherwise we will continuously make mistakes.

Comment: Did a Canadian just remove the "submissive language"?

Comment: Did a Jon B just try to be funny?

Comment: Poor @Toronto. His sense of humor was damaged in a freak laser accident.

Comment: Better to have had humour and lost it than to never have had it at all, eh Jon?

Comment: Touché, my dear. Touché.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I took a quick look through your questions and here are some things I saw, which *may* have contributed to some downvotes (as others have said, without comments one cannot know for sure what the exact reason was in each circumstance):

- poor grammar and spelling. This is not Twitter or Facebook; we expect complete, well-formed sentences here. You have room to spell out words completely; please do so!  For example, proper words are "your", "you", and "thanks", not "ur", "u" and "thx".
- a "do my work for me" attitude. Instead of saying "here is my code; it doesn't work", it helps to describe exactly *what* the problem is, the specific error message you receive, and what you have tried so far to fix the problem.  Ask a specific question: "how can I fix the condition so that the code is entered when <action> happens", rather than "The else condition in this code does not work well."
- incomplete and unclear titles. There are thousands of questions being asked on Stack Overflow every hour; to get the attention of those who are most likely to help, the title must be *clear* and *specific*.
- overly submissive language. "thx for ur feedback sir" is irritating to people who are simply trying to help. They're not your boss, they're a peer.

I would suggest reading [Jon Skeet's guide to Writing the Perfect Question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), and considering which points you might apply to your own posts.  You may also find [How to Ask Questions the Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) of value.

Comment: @Ether you are very true. but sir simple question is if somebody ask question and you realize that is important one and profitable for you but there is language problem and grammer not well than what will you going to do with that?

Comment: "You have room to spell out words completely; please do so! **e.g.** ..." LOL.

Comment: @Bill - fixed. :)

Comment: Very nice, this was the kind of feedback I meant in my answer

Comment: @mahesh, you may want to see [Is English required on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow) (note: it's long). The short version: if you make a good faith effort to ask your question, we'll make a good faith effort to answer it, usually including editing to clarify your meaning; but ultimately, SO is not in the business of supporting all languages, and if you can't be easily understood, you're not likely to get good answers.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64055/confusion-on-certain-comments-against-question-asked  See my answer.

Comment: @mahesh sir why is question considered profitable?  I have not seen any money change hands on stack overflow.  Plus, all questions asked are important to the person asking... We are free to up or down vote based on whatever criteria we like, and you're free to take it personally or take it in stride.

Comment: Great points except for the last paragraph.  *Please* don't link to ESR's horrible screed.  [Jon Skeet's version](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) is much easier to digest.

Comment: @Fosco "profitable" doesn't necessarily relate to money.

Comment: to learn better english it will take a long time and which i don't have that means this meta stackoverflow is not for me. in my world every person is respectful and i am not going to leave this good habbit to address someone as sir so it's better to leave this meta stackoverflow.

Comment: @Fosco Sir, That means u don't know importance of question. Do u Really know the stackoverflow?

Comment: @mahesh - we're trying to teach you something about the English language and the norms of Stack Overflow. You don't need to address anyone here as "sir". Especially the women.

Comment: @mahesh: I would just like to point out that many people would prefer *not* to be called "sir". Particularly Ether, whom you would *never* call "sir" if you met her in real life.

Comment: @aarobot: thanks, will add that link.

Comment: Wait @Ether isn't a sir?  Are you a Hir then? (hehe, that's supposed to be a play on words) `:P`

Comment: @jinguy - she's a cat. The correct way to address a cat is "stupid cat".

Comment: @mahesh: are you the only person from your region who uses these sites? Do the others call everyone "sir"?

Comment: @Jon I thought it was "damn cat"

Comment: Oh! it was big mistake from me for recognized of person weather he or she. my apologizes Ether. Actually i don't know about your gender. am sorry for that.

Comment: @John Saunders, Sir do you believe that our hands having fingers are same size. if not than how can people have same behavior. it's depend up to their living size,thought,religion and many more things is their to cause the people being defer.

Comment: I think the addressing people with respectful is not well here. so what to do. shall i leave my attitude to addressing people with respect.?

Comment: @mahesh As far as I am aware, in the general english-speaking world, "Sir" is used as a respectful form of address towards a person whose name you do not know (like when you need to talk to somebody on the street). When you know people's names - which is the case here - just use them. No need for an additional salutation. No need to be too deferential - we are all equal here

Comment: @Pekka Now i understand we are equal here. No need for additional salutation. i am trying my self to be like you and other people. as we all are here for only flow of knowledge.

Comment: @mahesh: I mean if nobody else does it, then maybe neither should you. Otherwise you will not be considered polite - you will be considered strange. That's fine if you wish to be considered to be strange.

Comment: @Jon B: cats may not be able to talk, but I hope I have proven that with the right technology, cats can be just as good programmers as mere humans! Now dogs, on the other paw... have you seen a dog do as well on Stack Overflow? I thought not! :)

Comment: @Ether - so is that what my cat is doing when she sits on my keyboard?

Answer (score 6):

Explanations are not mandatory on downvotes. Some users will leave an explanations, some won't. Also, not every downvote is cast for a good reason :)

If you are unsure about whether something's wrong with your input, one way to find out about it would be to post the links here on Meta. Somebody will surely be able to come up with some helpful advice.

Comment: Sir, there is no system for downvote. first asked him reason and than let to do downvote. It should prevent misuse of downvoting what u think sir.

Comment: @mahesh this has been discussed a hundred times, always with the result that it's best the way it is. See @Ether's answer for some constructive feedback

Answer (score 3):

Bottom line is unless the person down voting adds a comment then you will never know.

See this question [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63895/who-has-downvoted-me-and-why/63897#63897) and another one [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22934/so-annoyed-with-no-comment-vindictive-downvoting) for further information.

Comment: Sir, simple i think if i know already than there is no reason to ask again such a thing.

Comment: if i know i am asking or doing wrong thing than how can i ask that?

Answer (score 3):

The primary goal of voting is to sort the answers by quality. An answerer learning from his mistakes is secondary. If some kind of justification was required for downvoting, fewer people would downvote and we would be less successful in meeting our primary goal.

The system is imperfect. If you really want to know why you were downvoted, you can post a comment to your answer asking for an explanation. Nobody is required to answer you, of course, so you may not get a response at all.

Comment: ...and you may get down-voted for the comment itself, if you're sufficiently annoying about it...